# Fieldname modification in models SQLalchemy using ALEMBIC throws "Duplicate Column Name Error"

Tags: model, sqlalchemy, database-migration, alembic, sqlalchemy-migrate

**My Previous Model:**

```
class sample(Base):
    __tablename__ = "sample"
    id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True,index=True)
    Name = Column(String(30),index=True)
```

**My Latest Model:**

```
class sample(Base):
    __tablename__ = "sample"
    id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True,index=True)
    name = Column(String(30),index=True)
```

I ran the command `alembic revision --autogenerate -m "changed Name field to name"`

**My migrations details generated:**

```
def upgrade():

op.add_column('sample', sa.Column('name', sa.String(length=1000), nullable=False))
op.drop_column('sample', 'Name')
```

**I am getting the following error while upgrading head (alembic upgrade head ):**

```
    sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError) (1060, "Duplicate column name 'name'")
[SQL: ALTER TABLE sampleADD COLUMN `name` VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

Alembic is trying to drop existing column and trying to create new column, but i want to update the particular column.
How can I achieve this??

Answer (score 0):

You probably want [alter_column](https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/ops.html#alembic.operations.Operations.alter_column):

```py
op.alter_column('sample', 'Name', new_column_name='name')
```